# Gradually hide placeholder for datepicker value

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to try to implement a gradually hidden placeholder on my following datepicker:

```
<b-input-group class="input-datepicker">
    <b-input-group-prepend>
       <b-datepicker
              v-model="datepicker"
              button-only
              locale="en-US"
       ></b-datepicker>
    </b-input-group-prepend>
    <b-input
           v-model="datepicker"
           type="text"
           placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
           autocomplete="off"
           class="mr-0"
    ></b-input>
</b-input-group>
```

I use Vuejs with bootstrap-vue and my date Format is YYYY-MM-DD

I wish to have, for example, on input field at beginning `____-__-__` and we gradually input data, we have for example `2020-__-__` or `2020-0_-__` and reversely

I have searched in Internet and i don't find any good answers.

Sorry for my English if is not correct, i'm french

Thank you in advance

Best Regards,

Comment: *"I have searched the Internet and I don't find any good answers"* is not a valid research effort. Please update your question with what you tried (code-wise), and link any documentation stating what you tried should work. Without research effort, your question is a code-for-me-because-i-cant request. In fewer words, a client request.

Comment: Have you considered using [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) or [imask.js](https://imask.js.org/)? (First two hits on a search for *"input formatter js"*).They both have vue implementations.

Comment: Hello,

It's ok for the mask, i use imask.js

Thank you for your help !

Best Regards